# jquery class and display change.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make 1 form in multiple screens whit 1 submit button.
This is what i got this far but i'm stuck in jquery and hoped that someone could help me an say what i'm doing wrong here.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <ul id="stappen">
        <li id="step_1" class="selected">1. step_1</li>
        <li id="step_2" class="">2. step_2</li>
        <li id="step_3" class="">3. step_3</li>
        <li id="step_4" class="">4. step_4</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="stappen">
        <div id="content_step_1" class="content_step" style="display: block;">content step 1</div>
        <div id="content_stap_2" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 2</div>
        <div id="content_stap_3" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 3</div>
        <div id="content_stap_4" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 4</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    (function() {
        var body = $('body');
        $('.step_2').bind('click', function(){
            body.toggleClass('step_2');
            return false;
        });
    })();
</script>
</html>
```

The thing what i wan't to do is:
When li step_2 is clicked li id="step_2" class=""- changes "class" to "selected" and  "display" changes "none" to "block" like in this code is at the moment step 1 is selected and display: block.Afther all of this changes everything from step 1 must be the same as everything else :) -->class empty and display to none.

I know there is something wrong whit the jquery code but i don't know how to make it wright.
every try i did converted in an error or din't work, this is why ifilled in the script whish i know is partialy good.

I hope somebody can help me and/or point me in the right direction.

thnx in advanced.

Comment: I think you need to learn more about jquery selectors. In your code you are binding a click event to a class that dose't exist $('.step_2').bind('click', function(){}); all your li's have ID's not classes. Start there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ricardo says, you can not use same ID as for UL as for DIV. You have to fix it. Here example of improved you code version:
HTML

```
  <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <ul id="ul_stappen">
            <li id="step_1" class="selected">1. step_1</li>
            <li id="step_2" class="">2. step_2</li>
            <li id="step_3" class="">3. step_3</li>
            <li id="step_4" class="">4. step_4</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="div_stappen">
            <div id="content_step_1" class="content_step" style="display: block;">content step 1</div>
            <div id="content_stap_2" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 2</div>
            <div id="content_stap_3" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 3</div>
            <div id="content_stap_4" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 4</div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
  .selected{color:red}
```

JAVSCRIPT

```
(function() {
            $('#ul_stappen>li').on('click',function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
                $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('#div_stappen>div').filter(function(){return $(this).css('display')==='block'}).hide();
                $('#div_stappen>div').eq($(this).index()).show();   
                }
            });

    })();
```

And [Working JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ldmyygs/1/)

Hope this help you

Comment: thnx for your tips and example, i see now what i did wrong.
also thnx Vijay and Riccardo .
I've voted this as the answer because of the fiddle for futher reference for other users.

Answer (score 1):

You should not repeat IDs in HTML. The id `"stappen"` is repeated for both `UL` and `DIV` below that.

Let's assume that UL id is "ul_stappen" and DIV id is "div_stappen":

```
<ul id="ul_stappen">
...
</ul>

<div id="div_stappen">
..
</div>
```

Now we can achive your required effect with the jQuery code below:

```
$( '#ul_stappen' ).on('click', 'li', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
    };

    // show hide proper content divs
    var oldIndex = $ulStappen.find( 'selected' ).index();
    var newIndex = $(this).index();
    $( '#div_stappen li' ).eq( oldIndex ).hide();
    $( '#div_stappen li' ).eq( newIndex ).show();

    // add/remove 'selected' for proper li's
    // this must be the last part to be done
    $( '#ul_stappen' ).find( 'selected' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
    $(this).addClass( 'selected' );
});
```

Good luck, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

First issue: you have two elements with the same id (steppen). It's a mistake. For my code to work you need to change the second element id in "steppendiv".
Second issue: the first content id is step, while the other three are stAp (with the "a" instead "e"). For my code to work you need to change them and make all "content_step_1" (_2 _3 and so on)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#stappen" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
        $( "#stappen li" ).removeClass( "selected" );
        $( this ).addClass( "selected" );
        var liId = $( this ).attr( "id" );
        var splittedId = liId.split( "_" );
        var newId = "#content_step_" + splittedId[ 1 ];
        $( "#stappendiv > div" ).hide();
        $( newId ).show();
    });
});
```